# One layout for different tablet dimensions

Tags: android, android-layout

My goal is to create One layout that works for different tablet dimensions.
The app will present the information on Landscape mode.

In my case, I have these two tablets to test, they are 7 inches but with different dimensions:

Acer Iconia One 7 B1-770 Model: A5007
Physical Characteristics
Height: 0.4" (9.5 mm)
Width : 4.3" (108.8 mm)
Depth : 7.4" (189 mm)
Weight (Approximate): 280 g
1024 x 600

Samsung Tab 4 7' Model: SM-T230NU
Dimensions:  186.9 x 107.9 x 9 mm (7.36 x 4.25 x 0.35 in)
Resolution:  800 x 1280 pixels (~216 ppi pixel density)

How can I achieve this goal?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to create Different values folder for different screens in res folder with folder name Like this

```
values-sw720dp          10.1” tablet 1280x800 mdpi

values-sw600dp          7.0”  tablet 1024x600 mdpi

values-sw480dp          5.4”  480x854 mdpi 
values-sw480dp          5.1”  480x800 mdpi 

values-xhdpi            4.7”   1280x720 xhdpi 
values-xhdpi            4.65”  720x1280 xhdpi 

values-hdpi             4.0” 480x800 hdpi
values-hdpi             3.7” 480x854 hdpi

values-mdpi             3.2” 320x480 mdpi

values-ldpi             3.4” 240x432 ldpi
values-ldpi             3.3” 240x400 ldpi
values-ldpi             2.7” 240x320 ldpi
```

Comment: I have a doubt, for the Acer Iconia One 7 B1-770 Model: A5007 the screen dimensions in pixels is 1024 ** 552, in which folder do I put the values?

Comment: it goes under `values-sw600dp` for `7.0  tablet 1024x600 mdpi`

Comment: The minimum is 15 to mark an answer. I have only 13. Sorry man

Answer (score 2):

Create `layout-sw600dp-land` folder with xml file for desired layout.
Add this attribute to your `AndroidManifest file`.

```
<supports-screens
    android:largeScreens="true"/> //for tablets 7'
```